# Getting System.AccessViolationException when running project in visual studio 2015 Win 10 TP via Parallel on mac

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to run project in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 installed on Windows 10 Technical Preview over mac via Parallel Desktop 10.

Project creation and build goes fine, but when I try to run it in debugger mode i get following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

FYI - It runs fine if I try "Start Without Debugging".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem in VS 2013 on Windows 10 after update to 10041 build.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows 10 preview build 10049.

As I updated my PC from Windows 10 10041 --> 10049 and this problem is resolved.

Comment: Please explain what you mean.  How does this solve the problem?

Comment: I updated my pc from windows 10 10041 --> 10049, this problem resolved. (Sorry, i speak english not well)